# Wicket Facebook Login Integration

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, wicket

currently I am evaluating the integration of a Facebook Login Button within our existing Apache Wicket Web Application. At the moment no further functionality is needed else than SSO with Facebook.

Searching the web directed me to a few approaches, but they seem to be broken, no longer supported or just not state of the art, for example wicket-facebook, restFB or Facebook Login with JavaScript-SDK.

All in all, my approaches led to no errors, but also no Facebook Login Button beeing displayed, also regarding the showfaces flag.

I am using Wicket with Maven.

Could I get some suggestions for the way to got in 2016?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Few years ago I used https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava to create a Wicket Panel with authen buttons for Google, Facebook and GitHub for an application. Unfortunately I was not allowed to open source the solution.